# How to retrieve max id without using group by?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want retrieve max id but I don't want use group by in mysql.

This is my query with group by:

```
select max(id), nleadpk 
from `schedule` 
group by nleadpk
```

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean max(id) for the whole table, or for each nleadpk? But, describe why you don't want use group by!?!

Comment: yes u right. but i dont want use group by .. if you have answer then give me its important for me

Comment: But you still haven't told us which result you want? One row, or several rows, which max etc... Sample data, and expected result please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to use `group by` and still want to get the max id for each `nleadpk` you can use `left join` as

```
select t.* 
from schedule t 
left join schedule t1 on t1.nleadpk = t.nleadpk 
and t1.id > t.id 
where t1.id is null ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
select id, nleadpk from `schedule` order by id DESC limit 1;
```

You also can do direct query like below.. its working fine

```
select Max(id), nleadpk from `schedule`;
```

I mentioned both queries as you mentioned both tags

Comment: i want max(id) for the whole table, or for each nleadpk

Answer (score 0):

try subselect:

```
select 
   (select max(id) from schedule) as maxId, 
nleadpk from schedule
```

if just to know max(id)

```
select max(id) as maxId from schedule
```